# Match two planes with different origin locations (Blender Python Matrix Math)

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics, matrix

[image: Two Planes]

We see two identical Plane objects: A(blue) and B(red)
They are oriented arbitrarily in the 3D space.
Notice that the origin of A is located in the center and the origin of B is located in the lower left corner.

The problem:
What is the python code in Blender that will match the shapes of A to B perfectly.

I tried to match the matrices:

```
A.matrix_world = B.matrix_world
```

This matches location, rotation and scale of the objects but I still need to offset A by half width and half height in order to fit them perfectly.

Is it possible to do that with some of the available Matrix functions in Blender?

Comment: Are these both single face planes?

Comment: Yes they are single face Plane objects.
Maybe I should upload the blend file for more clarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Face centre as "Pseudo Origin"**

Given we have 2 single face planes, will make the face centre the *"pseudo origin"* and match that.

Test script, moving "Plane.001" to "Plane".  The difference in face centre coordinates vector is used to create a local transformation matrix. Premultiplying this by the matrix world will translate the "face centres" to match.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
# going to match transform of p2 to p1
p1 = scene.objects["Plane"]
mw = p1.matrix_world
p2 = scene.objects["Plane.001"]

# local offsets
o1 = p1.data.polygons[0].center
o2 = p2.data.polygons[0].center
# match the face centers global coords
# local translation matrix
LTM = Matrix.Translation(o1 - o2)
p2.matrix_world = mw * LTM
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me!
I will post slightly modified version that takes origins instead of face centers, but it doesn't deviate much from this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my slightly modified version of **batFINGER**'s solution:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
from mathutils import Vector

A = bpy.data.objects["A"]
B = bpy.data.objects["B"]

# local offsets
# The origin of A is in the center (positive dimensions divided by 2)
# The origin ob B is at lower left corner (zeroes)

# local translation matrix
LTM = Matrix.Translation(A.dimensions/2 - Vector())

# match Planes - A to B

A.matrix_world = B.matrix_world * LTM
```

This will work if one of the origins is in the center of the Plane and the other origin is in the lower left corner, and both planes A and B don't have applied rotation to them